# Getting Firefox's history

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-history

I am making a windows application to get a list of accessed website addresses of Firefox browser. I have no idea how to achieve this ? I am thinking accessing cache may be fine but computer cache contains more information than those I actually need. Would you please recommend a COM or method used to get this done ? I am grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox

Comment: Just kidding. Anyway, in SO, it is good practice to post some code you have tried for such questions. Otherwise you will get such responses from idiots like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses SQLite databases to store most of it's information. So probably easiest way to achive this would be study of this database files, and then all should be as simple as writing a couple of SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you, if I don't use firefox but Safari or Opera, what should I do to get all accessed urls ?

Comment: In both cases, most probably, you need to reverse engineer, in some way, storage structure used by this browsers to store history and use it. IE maybe have some API to get this info in more 'cultivated' way.

Answer (score 0):

History is stored in a SQLLIte database and can be accessed using the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Places_history_service

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Places